# Не могу дотянутся до свойства обькта

Tags: php, mysql

Возвращаю из бд данные с помощью PDP::FETCH_CLASS

```
   public function authenticate($username=NULL,$password=NULL)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ";
    $sql.= " WHERE username =? ";
    $sql.= " AND password =? ";
    $sql.= " LIMIT 1 ";
    $res =$this->_db->run($sql,[$username,$password])->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS,__CLASS__,[$this->_db]);
    return $res;/*
    if(!empty($res)){
        return array_shift($res);
    }else{
        return false;
    }*/
}


print_r($user->authenticate("admin",'123qwe'));
Array ( [0] => Modules\User1 Object ( [id] => 8 [username] => admin 
[password] => 123qwe [first_name] => wow [last_name] => wow 
[_db:Modules\User1:private] => Modules\MyPDO Object ( ) ) )
var_dump($user->id);// NULL
```

Почему NULL? У меня в классе User1 есть как свойства соответствующие полям в таблице. И Если я на ошибаюсь fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS... - метод должен возвратить новый экземпляр запрашиваемого класса, проецируя столбцы на соответствующие (их именам) свойства в классе. В чем тогда косяк мой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых Вы возвращаете список с результатами, а не один конкретный элемент.
Во-вторых Вы показали что возвращает метод

```
print_r($user->authenticate("admin",'123qwe'));
```

а потом пытаетесь достать информацию из объекта с помощью которого вы достаёте информацию

```
var_dump($user->id);
```

попробуйте сделать так:

```
$users = $user->authenticate("admin",'123qwe')); //вернули массив с пользователями
$userObject = reset($users); //берём первый элемент из массива
var_dump($userObject->id);
```

Comment: Понял , спасибо